# MySQL Database backup automatically on a windows server

Tags: mysql, database, backup

Is there a way to back up MySQL database automatically at certain times of the day for designated servers or send an email with an attachment.. Which ever do you think is the best and safest way to achieve this?

Comment: You can use MySQLBackupFTP to backup your MySQL databases and set a schedule as you need. Also, this tool can send email confirmations on job success or failure. http://mysqlbackupftp.com/mysql-blog/how-to-backup-mysql-databases/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I would use Windows Task Scehduler/cron (depending on your system) and [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html). Scroll down in the link, it includes some insights how to achieve what you want.

Comment: Yes its seem this link has all the information I need hopefully I can put it together. Thank you very much Martin. and How do you use windows task scheduler in a server?

Comment: Task scheduler on Windows server is pretty much the same as on workstation. If you do not feel comfortable about it, you may get better answers on http://superuser.com/ or http://serverfault.com/. If you feel my answer has helped you to solve your problem, it would be kind of you to accept it.

Answer (score 30):

Best way to do this would be

```
mysqldump.exe --user=YourUserName --password=YourPassword --host=localhost --port=3306 --result-file="Path\dump.sql" --databases "DatabaseName1" "Database2"


mysqldump.exe --user=root --password=root  --host=localhost --port=3306 --result-file="c:\www\db\backup.%date:~10,4%%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%.sql" --default-character-set=utf8 --single-transaction=TRUE --databases "dbtest1" "dbtest2"
```

The pattern `backup.%date:~10,4%%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%.sql` will create a unique name (`backup20131010.sql`) each time it will run

Now you just need to call this command in your task scheduler. That's it. :)

Comment: Thanks @Tarun date format is not readable how can it change with YYYY-MM_DD format?

Comment: backup.%date:~10,4%%-date:~4,2%_date:~7,2%%.sql  @MohammadFaizanKhan hope this will help.

Comment: add this  --column-statistics=0 after mysqldump.exe to avoid getting this error: unknown table 'column_statistics'...

Comment: I added the whole parameters, but the date pattern is not working. Scheduler failed to start `mysqldump`. When I remove the patter, it works. Any suggestions? It's Windows Server 2019.

Answer (score 7):

You can add one of these commands to `Windows task scheduler`:

```
mysqldump –-user [username] –-password=[password] [database name] > [dump file]
```

or in a compact way:

```
mysqldump –u[username] –p[password] [database name] > [dump file]
```

or:

```
mysqldump -u[user] -p[password] --result-file="c:\<path>\backup.%DATE:~0,3%.sql" [database]
```

Answer (score 4):

`databaseW.2016,06,29-22,31,48-15.sql`

```
@echo off
rem Backup Database (Daily,via Task Scheduler)
rem databaseW
set filename="c:\xampp\dbk\databaseW.%date:~6,4%,%date:~0,2%,%date:~3,2%-%time:~0,2%,%time:~3,2%,%time:~6,2%-%time:~9,2%.sql"
c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe --user=root --password=dell@root --host=localhost --port=3306 --result-file=%filename% --default-character-set=utf8 --single-transaction=TRUE --databases "databaseW"
```

To create file whose name is based on the date and time, use `%date%` and `%time%`.
Note that the 2 variables are based on locale and cmd shell version

- open the cmd windows
- input `echo %time%` and `echo %date%`
  mine is `22:11:16.80`,`06/29/2016 Wed`
- substr the variable through `%variable:~startpos,length%`
  I want the time delimited by comma, so the cmd goes
  `echo %time:~0,2%,%time:~3,2%,%time:~6,2%,%time:~9,2%`
- to get a filename like `databaseW.2016,06,29-22,31,48-15.sql`
  use `set filename="databaseW.%date:~6,4%,%date:~0,2%,%date:~3,2%-%time:~0,2%,%time:~3,2%,%time:~6,2%-%time:~9,2%.sql"`
- check the `date` and `time` in advance
- use the `--result-file` option instead of `>`; According to the Mysql Manuel, the charset of file saved using ">" is `UTF-16`, while the `--result-file` follows the `--default-character-set`
- save to file `BackpDay-databaseW.cmd`
- add it to a new task `Action` and set a trigger (Windows Task Scheduler)

Answer (score 3):

I did the work, similar to what other people explained through... **but with little difference and extra work**:

1) I made a batch file 
2) Ran that batch file through windows scheduler 
3) Made appropriate schedule for that task 
4) Inside the batch file these steps are executed:

- 4-1) Prepared a file name based on current date
- 4-2) Got a backup by mysqldump.exe in the corresponding directory & file name
- 4-3) Made a compress file through 7-Zip app(install it) & then delete the uncompressed backup
- 4-4) Put a copy on our network File-Server

Here is a script(.bat) sample:

```
@echo off
set current=%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%
set filename="E:\MySQL Backups\DBName-%current%.sql"
set filename2="E:\MySQL Backups\DBName-%current%.zip"
echo %filename%
cd "E:\MySQL Backups"
C:\"Program Files"\MySQL\"MySQL Server 5.5"\bin\mysqldump.exe db_name --user=root --password=rootpass --host="127.0.0.1" --port=instancePort --result-file=%filename% --default-character-set=utf8 --single-transaction=TRUE
echo backup-finished

if exist %filename% (
    "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a %filename2% %filename%
    echo zip-finished
    del %filename%
)
if exist %filename2% (
    copy %filename2% "\\192.168.x.x\MySQL Backups"
    echo copy-finished
)
```