# MySQL Database backup on windows server -- not working with dynamic date

Tags: mysql, database, windows, backup, taskscheduler

I'm able to schedule a windows task to create a MySQL database backup based on advice given in this stackoverflow question:

[MySQL Database backup automatically on a windows server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666819/mysql-database-backup-automatically-on-a-windows-server)

This is my command:

```
mysqldump.exe --user=[user] --password=[password]  --host=localhost --port=3306 --result-file="c:\data\backup.sql" --default-character-set=utf8 --single-transaction=TRUE --databases "[database1]"
```

However, when I change my filename to include a dynamic date value as follows it doesn't create a backup anymore:

```
mysqldump.exe --user=[user] --password=[password]  --host=localhost --port=3306 --result-file="c:\data\backup%date:~10,4%%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%.sql" --default-character-set=utf8 --single-transaction=TRUE --databases "[database1]"
```

Note: when I run this command via commandline it successfully creates a backup with the correct filename: backup.20160707.sql.

But for some reason when I run the Windows Task which runs this command it is not creating the backup file. When I look at history it appears to have finished successfully. What's going on?

Comment: Task Scheduler is showing this error: 0x80070001

Comment: Running that command directly in Task Scheduler or within a batch file? Try the latter if you aren't already.

Comment: Moved my command to a batch file and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Ah that did work. I previously moved my command args to a batch file but forgot the mysqldump.exe prefix. I added that and it now works. Strange. Thanks for the help!